# Show the limit of a function doesn't exist

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

So, we are asked to say for which  $\alpha \in \mathbb Z$, the following limit exists: $$\lim_{x\to\ 0}\ \left(x^{\alpha}\ \mathrm{sin}(x)\ \mathrm{sin}\left( \frac{1}{x}\right)\right)$$

So far, I've been able to prove that for $\alpha\geq 0$, the limit exists. But when it comes to negative integers, I'm stuck. I checked with a program and it turns out that this limit does not exist if $\alpha$ is negative.

Thus, I've tried to find two sequences, $a_n$ and $b_n$ that both converge to $0$, but where $$\lim_{n\to+\infty} f(a_n) \neq \lim_{n\to+\infty} f(b_n)$$
where $f$ is the function above.

I've tried taking $a_n = \frac{1}{n}$, which gives me the following (knowing that alpha is negative) : $$\lim_{n\to+\infty} \left( n^{|\alpha |}\ \mathrm{sin}\left(\frac{1}{n} \right)\ \mathrm{sin}(n)\ \right) $$ which I don't know what it equals to, because $n^{|\alpha |}$ goes to infinity and $\mathrm{sin}\left(\frac{1}{n} \right)$ goes to $0$ (so it's an undetermined form).

I've also tried with $b_n=\frac{1}{\pi n}$, giving me: $$\lim_{n\to+\infty} \left( \pi^{|\alpha |}\ n^{|\alpha |}\ \mathrm{sin}\left(\frac{1}{\pi n} \right)\ \mathrm{sin}(n\pi)\ \right)=0$$ since $\mathrm{sin}(n\pi)$ is equal to $0$ for all n.

But apart from this, I really don't know what to do (and clearly, right now I haven't shown that for $\alpha<0$ the limit of the function as $x$ goes to $0$ doesn't exist).

Comment: for negative integers, you can simplify the problem by recognizing that sin(x)/x goes to 1 as x goes to 0--then look at what's left

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that, for $x\ne0$,
$$
x^a\sin(x)\sin\Bigl(\frac{1}{x}\Bigr)=
x^{a+1}\frac{\sin(x)}{x}\sin\Bigl(\frac{1}{x}\Bigr)
$$
so the limit you're looking for exists if and only if the limit of
$$
x^{a+1}\sin\Bigl(\frac{1}{x}\Bigr)
$$
does, because of the known limit $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin(x)}{x}=1$. If the limits exist, then they are equal.

If $a+1>0$, the limit is zero, because
$$
-|x|^{a+1}\le x^{a+1}\sin\Bigl(\frac{1}{x}\Bigr)\le |x|^{a+1}
$$
If $a+1\le0$, the limit does not exist, because…

---

Note added after comments.

> *Suppose $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=1$; if $\lim_{x\to a}g(x)$ exists (finite or infinite), then also $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)g(x)$ exists and is the same.*

Now apply this with $f(x)=\frac{\sin x}{x}$ and $g(x)=x^{a+1}\sin(1/x)$ and with $f(x)=\frac{x}{\sin x}$ and $g(x)=x^a\sin x\sin(1/x)$.

Comment: can you please explain why $x^asin(x)sin(1/x)=x^{a+1}sin(x)xsin(1/x)$?

Comment: @BeginningMath Doesn't $x^{a+1}/x=x^a$?

Comment: thank you, understood

Comment: I don't get why you say that "the limit exists if and only if the limit of $$x^{\alpha+1} \mathrm{sin} \left( \frac{1}{x} \right)$$ does". I mean you're not allowed to say that if a part of a function diverges when x goes to $0$, then the whole function diverges. Basically, if I did understand your answer correctly you used the product rule for limits, namely you said that finding the limit of our function is the same as finding the limit of $sin(x)/x$ times $x^a\ sin(1/x)$, which is correct of both limits exists, but which is incorrect when they do not

Comment: @Skyris It's just applying the limit product rule. See the addition.

Comment: @egreg I'm sorry but I still find this weird. Let me use your theorem step by step. The limit of $f$ is $1$. If the limit of $g$ exists, then limit of $f \cdot g$ exists and is the same. I cannot apply this theorem to my situation, because since I know the the limit of $g$ doesn't exist, I can't conclude that the limit of $f\cdot g$ doesn't exist too, because  if I did conclude this, I would be using the fact that the converse of your theorem is also true (which means that your statement should be an if and only if statement instead of an if statement).

Comment: @Skyris If the limit of $fg$ exists, then also the limit of $fg/f$ exists.

Comment: It took me years, but I finally got it xD

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

So we have this function $f$:
\begin{align}
f(x)=x^\alpha \sin(x)\sin\left( \frac 1 x\right)
\end{align}

Okay, let's show that the limit of $x\to 0$ does not exist  for $\alpha\leq -1$ using your thoughts with finding sequences. Let us use $a_n= \frac{2}{\pi n}$ (only one sequence is sometimes enough!). Now we have:
\begin{align}
f(a_n)= \left(\frac{\sin\left(\frac{2}{\pi n}\right)}{\frac{2}{\pi n}} \right)\left(\frac{2}{\pi n}\right)^{\alpha+1} \sin\left(\frac{\pi n}{2}\right)
\end{align}
So we can write:
\begin{align}
f(a_n) = b_n \left(\frac{2}{\pi n}\right)^{\alpha+1} \sin\left(\frac{\pi n}{2}\right)
\end{align}
Where $b_n \to 1$ (why?). Now look at the following:
\begin{align}
\limsup_{n\to\infty}f(a_n) = 
\begin{cases}
1 & \text{ if } &\alpha=-1\\
\infty & \text{ if } & \alpha<-1
\end{cases}
\end{align}
Similarly we have:
\begin{align}
\liminf_{n\to\infty}f(a_n) = 
\begin{cases}
-1 & \text{ if } &\alpha=-1\\
-\infty & \text{ if } & \alpha<-1
\end{cases}
\end{align}
You see that the limit does not even exist for one sequence. Therefore the limit cannot exist.

Comment: Thank you though, I finally get it.

Comment: @Skyris yes I see it, I removed the remark that was only true for real numbers.

Answer (score 0):

since we have $$\left|x^{\alpha}\sin(x)\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right|\le |x^{\alpha}|$$
and this tends to Zero if $$\alpha\geq 0$$
for $\alpha<0$ the Limit doesn't exist

Comment: You are using the squeeze theorem to show that the limit exists. However, when it comes to showing that a limit doesn't exist, I'm not sure if we can use the squeeze theorem.